# How xml to json converter in freeformatter.com works?

Tags: javascript, json, html, xml-parsing

Is anyone aware of how http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html works. This is the best ever converter I came across. I want to use this logic in my project too, to parse xml responses to json.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Like Quentin mentioned, freeformatter.com does not appear to be open source.

To address this issue GitHub user bramstein created a XSLT named XSLTJSON.
You can find it here https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson

Note: The purpose of XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is to transform XML into other formats.

Comment: I dont thing this is an npm package. I needed an npm package.

Comment: This is just a xslt  Stylesheet. To perform a transformation you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_xslt in combination with XSLTJSON